# How do I delete posts?

Tags: support

How do I delete one of my posts? I have been looking for an answer everywhere, but I can't find it!

Comment: Do you mean like when making a fence and you placed a post down, but put it in the wrong place or something?

Comment: Yes, and that is a good joke, :)

Comment: Oh my gosh, how did I not notice that!? (Face palm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check under the tag in your question, you'll see a delete option:

[image: Delete option]